# MVC app crashes after adding MEF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef

I'm working on an open source MVC project for a class and once one of the other students added MEF into the project it stopped running for me. it still runs for everyone else I've researched this for quite some time and asked the prof and haven't been able get anything working.

For the entire Error please see the following

http://pastebin.com/7qjanN3b

Here are the first lines of each section of the error page
NOTE:

> [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.]

NOTE: this is a single line on the error page I thought this was quite strange.

> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while composing the MEF
>   parts. Type(s): Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SecurityUtils,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager+ExecResult,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionStatus,
>
> REMOVED A FEW HUNDRED LINES OF GARBAGE PLEASE SEE LINK FOR FULL ERROR
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptContainer,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ObjectScriptContainer,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.IdBasedObjectScriptContainer,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TableScriptContainer,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptContainerFactory,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SfcDiscoveryNode,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SfcHierarchyDiscovery,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SfcDependencyDiscovery,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SfcDependencyDiscovery+SfcNodeVisitor,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SfcDependencyDiscovery+ScriptListContext,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyDiscovery,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ErrorLocation,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DependencyDiscoveryError,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DependencyDiscoverySink,
>   {6700AF61-4E8B-4423-BE3B-A43DE0C1B3B3},
>   {6700AF61-4E8B-4423-BE3B-A43DE0C1B3B3}+_*StaticArrayInitTypeSize=24,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server+d*_0,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database+d_*0,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database+d*_3,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.CpuCollection+d_*0,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupMediaSet+<>c*_DisplayClass2,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupSet+<>c_*DisplayClassa,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection+d*_0,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker+d_*2,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker+d*_8,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer+<>c_*DisplayClass25,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabasePrefetchBase+d*_1,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ObjectScriptContainer+<>c__DisplayClass2,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  ,
>   Reason(s): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Running Win7 with SQL Express 2008 sp3 with sql manager installed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first confirm that you have the SqlEnum dll installed in the GAC on your machine.  You can check this by going to C:\Windows\assembly.  If something is missing, you may need to repair or reinstall the Sql Management Objects feature.  Also check that the version you have installed is the same version MEF is trying to load.

If you do have it installed, try using the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This can help you [find which dlls are failing to load](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx), and what steps the loader is going through in trying to load the dll.  This should help you narrow down where the issue is coming from.

Comment: The SqlEnum DLL is right where it should be I'll use that tool and see what I come up with.

Comment: Someone with more rep please mark this up it has resolved my issue. basically it's looking for Version 11.0.0.0 but I have 10.0.0.0 I'm assuming this is the difference between 2008 and 2008 R2, I will upgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: Verified Fixed 2012 SQL express install fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are missing a reference somewhere.  I would go back through the code and ensure that all your "using" statements are as they should be, as well as the project's references to the assemblies.

Comment: As I said, the program runs for everyone else which makes me think the code is fine. I'm just not sure how a missing using could cause that.    //Comment editing rules are a little dumb